# How can I select a specific jquery element value from inside a loop?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to put a string value in an array based on their position in relation to all of the elements with a class name.  I get an array of the indexes that I want to use now I want to use each of the index values to select the appropriate value.

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
    var dateInput = $("select[name='searchString']");
    var theClassTime = $("input.TextBoxDate");
    var checkedindex = [];
    var classday = [];

    $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) 
    {
        if (this.checked) 
        {
            // this works fine
            checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));

            // this is where I’m trying to select values based on index.
            var dayofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + checkedindex[i] + ")");

            classday.push(dayofclass);

            alert(classday);
        }
    });
});
```

Say checkedindex has values:  2,3,9 meaning at index 0 of checkedindex is 2, at 1=3 and at 2=9.  I want to use 2, 3 and 9 to do something like this:

```
var dayofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + checkedindex[i] + ")");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried looping through the selected courses. Then in your if statement if(this.checked) var addVal = this.innerhtml(); classday.push(addval);.

Comment: What I wrote above basically gets the value of teach input in selected courses that is checked. Stores that value then adds it to the array. I'm not sure if you're trying to get the html or just the index from the checkbox list

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look up the checkbox by id, you already have a reference to it. You can use `this` if you want the element or `$(this)` if you want the jquery object.

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
    var dateInput = $("select[name='searchString']");
    var theClassTime = $("input.TextBoxDate");
    var checkedindex = [];
    var classday = [];

    $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) 
    {
        if (this.checked) 
        {
            // this works fine
            checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));

            // this is where I’m trying to select values based on index.
            // this will get the value of the current checkbox
            var dayofclass = $(this).val(); 

            classday.push(dayofclass);

            alert(classday);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2TJLm/

Is that basically what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please place your answer here, rather than just a link to it

Comment: var dayofclass = $(this).val(); is not doing the correct orselection.  I was trying to use this:  $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + checkedindex[i] + ")") as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

**Make Things Easier**

Just use one array to store...

```
var selectedCourses = $("input[name='selectedCourses']"),
    theClassTime = $("input.TextBoxDate"),
    checkedindex = [],
    go = true;

function dothings() {
    selectedCourses.each(function (i) {//for each possible selection
        var cur = theClassTime.eq(i);//get current selected

        //do something
        if (this.checked) {
            cur.addClass('red');//for checked
            if (go) { checkedindex.push(i); }//store initial selections
        } else {
            cur.removeClass('red');//for non checked
        }
    });
    go = false;//turn off
    alert(checkedindex);//show stored array
}

selectedCourses.on('change', function() { dothings(); });//run on event

dothings();//run initially
```

**[made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/eAXa8/)** *not sure about markup being used, so it's just a visual representation*

Comment: Here's my scenario:  When the user lands on this page.  Some boxes are already checked.  I create an array to collect the positions of those checked boxes which I was successful in doing.  Now if the user make changes to the form, during the click function I want to use previously saved index from the earlier array to do some work.

Comment: No problem, updated the the solution to be able to use the initially stored array.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  The code allows me to use data stored in arrays on page load and compare them at the time of submitting the form.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


      $(function () {

          $("#date").datepicker();
          $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
          var dateInput = $("select[name='searchString']");

          var checkedindex = [];
          var classdate = [];
          var classtime = [];
          var dayofclass = [];
     $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
         if (this.checked) {

             checkedindex.push(parseInt(i));

         }

     });
     for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
         var ind = checkedindex[x];

         var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
         var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
         var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

         classdate.push(dateofclass);
         classtime.push(timeofclass);
         dayofclass.push(classday);


         alert(classdate[x].val() + "  " + classtime[x].val() + " " + dayofclass[x].val());
     }
 });
</script>
```